# Is there a lower bound for the connection time of Nearby Connections API?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I would like to know if there is a lower bound when it comes to connection time using Nearby Connections API.

Is it different based on the Strategy?

I've read here on stack overflow that on *P2P_POINT_TO_POINT* there is an internal protocol to check the available connection methods for both devices, and then they switch to this method.
I have small payloads (so the Strategy is not a problem), and my issue now is understanding the time constraints of this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy shouldn't significantly affect the time to connect. In all 3 cases, Bluetooth is the primary mechanism for advertising/scanning/connecting. It's only after both sides accept the connection that they try to upgrade to different WiFi technologies.

Expect ~3sec lower bound for connecting and ~7sec upper bound. If the phone is in a bad state, the upper bound can unfortunately go much much higher (~1min) although you can disconnect at any time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
As a side question: is it possible to reconnect to a device after asking for disconnection?
I tried it with  Point to Point strategy but it seems it's not possible (using the same id first discovered), but I did not find anything about it on the docs

Comment: It's not officially blessed, but not explicitly blocked either. There's some caching (of mac addresses, IPs, etc) when you scan for devices. This cache is cleared whenever a new scan is started, or if your process unbinds from the Nearby process. There's a timer that automatically unbinds after ~15sec of disuse (no active scans, advertisements, or connections), so you may be running into that. We generally advise you to rescan, since that keeps your list of nearby devices fresh too.

Comment: Ohh, I get it now. Thank you for your great answers!